# call method when vue multiselect

Tags: vue-component

I have a vue multiselect and when I select an item from that it should call to vue method. I have tried as follows and it didn't work. what the wrong with it?

```
<multiselect v-model="value" placeholder="Search Categories" @change="getItems"
    :options="categories" :taggable="true" :custom-label='categoriesWithTitle' track-by='id'
    :show-labels="false">
</multiselect>
```

```
 -method call
    methods: {
        getItems(){
            alert("Test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is connected change event in component?

Comment: I am not clear. what did you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<multiselect v-model="value" placeholder="Search Categories" @input="getItems"
    :options="categories" :taggable="true" :custom-label='categoriesWithTitle' track-by='id'
    :show-labels="false">
</multiselect>
```

**@input="getItems"**

Answer (score 0):

from the docs: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-asynchronous-select

you should use `@search-change` to trigger a function call on search query changes.